# Mapping of localhost

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications, localhost

We generally use

```
http://localhost:8080/mywebapp
```

for running web applications.

What I want is to access my web app using something like this:

```
WWW.example.com
```

How to achieve this?
Actually what i want to ask is that how URL like WWW.example.com is mapped to web applications? Assuming that i am using tomcat server.

Comment: You have to setup a local `DNS` server.

Answer (score 0):

In your Tomcats server.xml there already is a host element like:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="false">
...
</Host>
```

Copy that part and change the "name" attribute to your favorite domain name. Deploy your application into this new virtual host. You have to set your server port to 80 or you can map the app through Apache web server using mod_jk or mod_proxy. If you dont already have a domain you can edit your "hosts" file to create a locle one for testing. In Windows this file is located in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc. Add a line like:

```
127.0.0.1 www.mydomain.local
```

That should do the trick.